# Realistic Marvel indestructibility/immortality

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, evolution, natural-weapons

**Spoiler Alert**

> In the Marvel comics Carnage, Deadpool, Sabretooth, Wolverine  and their clones X-23 and Danken are immortal, and all are indestructible apart from Wolverine  and his brother which can be killed by decapitation, but as long as their skeleton is intact they will regenerate everything as seen in the nitro explosion.

At what levels can any of this be realistic?  And how?

In the real world :

- Can any of them develop (evolve) naturally as a species?
- How many calories would they need daily to survive this way?
- Can Wolverine, X-23 and Danken survive with metallic bones?
- How can all of them regenerate full limbs within days,and instantly in fight?
- Can Deadpool regenerate his own head and brain while remaining the same person?
- Can a symbiote like creature be compatible with any animal?
- Where do they get infinite matter to regenerate their whole bodies?
- Can a symbiote be liquid-like ?

Comment: As a single question, this is probably most easily answerable as "no, not realistic." However, you have a *bunch* of other potentially interesting questions laid out at the bottom of your post. Something like "What's the fastest an organism could realistically regenerate" could be an interesting question on its own if you put a bit of work into it.

Comment: Note that we have [already tackled the issues](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4312/6986) concerning Wolverine's regenerative ability.

Comment: I don't see how that "spoiler" is a spoiler at all, or why the whole thing needs to be put in a spoiler tag. It's vital information for the question and needs to be visible.

Answer (score 7):

Let's just settle for "no, none of this is realistic".

Comment: Let's just say that a comic book has no faint need to be realistic, and draw the appropriate conclusion.

Answer (score 6):

Since you went with "science based" and "reality check", the answer is: no.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, **nanotechnology**.

Other questions here [discussed realistic regeneration](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=Regeneration+is%3Aq).  The tech needs to know what to repair; that is, a set of plans. Clearly that is possible from within as anphibians do it. However, the body needs to still work in order to provide resources and metabolism. An independent self-contained system could make use of nanobots distributed across all tissues, and be robust enough to bootstrap itself up like a *seed* or *spore*. That is, growth won't just happen, but will need a source of material and energy.

If a targeted question is not a duplicate, it can be discussed in more detail on its own question along the lines of **what would extreme regeneration really be like?**

As for memories, the *actual* brain state needs to be backed up somewhere, assuming this being even uses a brain like ours. It might  be designed to be distributed and redundant.

Comment: I recall writing about the possible speed of limb regeneration but can't find it now.